# Is there a way to make Lookup always return the first encountered match in a column?

Tags: excel

I have user retention data that looks like this:

```
signup_date days    retention       
2/24/13 0   1
2/23/13 0   1
2/23/13 1   0.4855
2/22/13 0   1
2/22/13 1   0.4727
2/22/13 2   0.3647
2/21/13 0   1
2/21/13 1   0.5135
2/21/13 2   0.3879
2/21/13 3   0.3463
2/20/13 0   1
2/20/13 1   0.5402
2/20/13 2   0.4166
2/20/13 3   0.3615
2/20/13 4   0.3203
2/19/13 0   1
2/19/13 1   0.5317
2/19/13 2   0.4348
2/19/13 3   0.366
2/19/13 4   0.3077
```

The second column ("days") represents days elapsed since the signup date and the retention is based on that day and the signup_date (since retention can change over time). I need to make projections going forward, and unfortunately for me (since I would prefer to do this programmatically), my boss wants them in Excel. So I'm trying to use the Lookup() function to find the most recent value in the retention column that would match the "days" elapsed from a certain signup date.

Anyway, that's all prelude to the question, which is that right now if I enter the formula:

```
=lookup(1,B:B,C:C)
```

where B:B is "days" and C:C is retention, it doesn't necessarily return the first (i.e. most recent) retention value in the data set. For example, in this case, I need the cell to be 0.4855, but the formula may give me 0.4727 (which is the second "days=1" row). Is there any way to configure it to do this or is there another function that will do what I need?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `LOOKUP`, use the `VLOOKUP` function - it has another parameter that specifies that the data is not in order:

```
=VLOOKUP(1,$B:$C,2,0)
```

This will return you the entry in the second column of your range `B:B` where "1" is found in the first column of your range. Do not forget the `0` at the end, as this tells Excel to search row by row (vs. a binary search as `LOOKUP`or omitting the parameter would do).

Alternative:
`VLOOKUP`is the simple formula and default for those situation. The even better, as more flexible way is to use `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,$B:$B,0))
```

This will do exactly the same, just that you have a bit more flexibility and don't need to include the "second column from the lookup data"...

HTH!